# Covariance in Scala - Dont understand example

Tags: scala

I was reading this post...
http://codedefinition.com/scala-type-covariance-and-contravariance.html

I dont understand the difference between the following...

```
def sayHi(people:List[Person]) = people.map { println _ }
def sayHi[T <: Person](people: List[T]) = people.map { println _ }
```

Arent they the same thing? The latter says T must be a subclass of Person no?

Comment: Ignore that blog post. The examples are poor code that don't really help with the explanation. Try [Twitter's Scala school's explanation](http://twitter.github.io/scala_school/type-basics.html#variance) instead. There is a very good reason for using the second method, but the blog post doesn't explore it. It allows you to use `T` in your method signature rather than just the less explicit `Person`. i.e. you could return an `Employee`

Comment: Thanks ggovan. I did some other looking around and understand a little better now. The List type in Scala is Covariant so thats why the former  works above but if you were using java.util.List which is Invariant it wouldnt i.e. you wouldnt be able to pass in java.util.List[Employee] to type of java.util.List[Person], but in the latter you would. You are right in saying its not a very illustrative post and ill check out the code school.